# Reload the start activity?

Tags: android

Pseudocode :

```
The initial Activity starts. (ActivityStartScreen)

A button is pressed that starts a new Activity (ActivityOtherScreen) by using an Intent.

The new Activity has a button that loads the initial Activity.
```

My question is, is the original activity gone once it 'loses focus' (when the 1st button is pressed), or is it stored somewhere, and is there a way to retrieve it?

Currently, Im re-creating the original activity with an intent. I bet this isnt the proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous Activities are stored in the Activity stack, to return to previous activity, just call `finish()` on current activity. Note that this way you lose the 2nd activity.

Answer (score 1):

You simply must call the `finish()` method from your second activity to go back with the states all being the same.

[Here](http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/24/android-how-to-switch-between-activities/) is a helpful warriorpoint blog post tutorial that will walk you through it.